How to get the value of expression if I have some equalities?
I have this system of equations:
-(2 z)/(3) - (x^2 + y^2 - 2 z^2)/(3) = 47/300;
-(2 x)/(3) - (z^2 + y^2 - 2 x^2)/(3) = -31/300;
-(2 y)/(3) - (z^2 + x^2 - 2 y^2)/(3) = -7/50;

I mustn't find values of x y z but I have to find value of the expression.
(2 z)/(3) - (x^2 + y^2 - 2 z^2)/(3)=?
And if Mathematica tries to find {x y z} it turns bad, becaus it finds them numerically and returns numerical value of expression, but I definitely know that there is rational solution.
How can I do it using Mathematica?

it finds them numerically If you used Solve[] and saw what you thought were numerical solutions, they were actually the way Mathematica displays exact Root[] expressions.

I definitely know that there is rational solution. That seems unlikely, since when Mathematica computes $x, y, z,$ and then your desired expression it doesn't get any rational values. It gets roots of 4th degree polynomials.

Eliminate[ ] will do the job. Put
eqns={-(2 z)/(3)-(x^2+y^2-2 z^2)/(3)==47/300,
      -(2 x)/(3)-(z^2+y^2-2 x^2)/(3)==-31/300,
      -(2 y)/(3)-(z^2+x^2-2 y^2)/(3)==-7/50};
expr=(2 z)/(3)-(x^2+y^2-2 z^2)/(3);

Let u be the variable corresponding to the possible values of the expr. Then,

Mathematica says there are algebraic solutions but no rational solutions.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {-(2  z)/(3) - (x^2 + y^2 - 2  z^2)/(3) == 47/300,
   -(2  x)/(3) - (z^2 + y^2 - 2  x^2)/(3) == -31/300,
   -(2  y)/(3) - (z^2 + x^2 - 2  y^2)/(3) == -7/50};

expr = (2  z)/(3) - (x^2 + y^2 - 2  z^2)/(3);

Using the equations to simplify your expression,
expr2 = FullSimplify[expr, eqns]

(* 47/300 + (4 z)/3 *)

Solving the equations for z,
solz = Solve[eqns, z, {x, y}];

The exact values of the expression are then
expr3 = expr2 /. solz // FullSimplify


Use ToRadicals to obtain a radical representation of the exact expression. To approximate the expression values with rationals
approx = expr3 // N[#, 10] & // Rationalize[#, 0] &

(* {-(86516/145973), -(41025/78647), -(51551/375504), 109941/52120} *)

The approximation errors are
(expr3 - approx) // N

(* {-3.56053*10^-11, 4.23624*10^-11, 3.60542*10^-12, -9.94946*10^-11} *)


You can always approximate a real number by arbitrarily close rational numbers.  The OP states that there is a rational solution ( expr is rational iff z is rational) and so you should find such a solution or demonstrate that there is none. I guess all that is obvious for you, however it seems that the OP makes a confusion between a rational solution and an algebraic solution, while all solutions of the problem are algebraic.

As stated as has been observed the system of equations does not yield a rational value for the desired expression.
I suspect this question is about transforming the set of equations into another set of equations. I am not explaining why or what value. Note the the second and third equations are unaffected by z->-z but this substitution is the desired expression for first.
 u = {-(2 z)/(3) - (x^2 + y^2 - 2 z^2)/(3) == 47/300,
   -(2 x)/(3) - (z^2 + y^2 - 2 x^2)/(3) == -31/300,
   -(2 y)/(3) - (z^2 + x^2 - 2 y^2)/(3) == -7/50};
p = u[[1]] /. z -> -z
sol = NSolve[u, {x, y, z}];
ns = {x, y, -z} /. sol;
r = Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ ns;
{p[[1]], u[[2, 1]], u[[3, 1]]} /. r // Rationalize // Grid
{p, u[[2]], u[[3]]} /. r

Note that False in last line appears to be a numerical precision issue. The new system of equations is satisified by {x,y,-z}.

You can see the two systems solutions and the symmetries nicely:
pts={x,y,z}/.sol;
plot1 = Show[
  ContourPlot3D[u, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3], Mesh -> None], 
  ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> {Blue,  PointSize[0.04]}], 
  ImageSize -> 300];
plot2 = Show[
  ContourPlot3D[{p, Evaluate@u[[2]], Evaluate@u[[3]]}, {x, -2, 
    2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
   Mesh -> None], 
  ListPointPlot3D[ns, PlotStyle -> {Red,  PointSize[0.04]}], 
  ImageSize -> 300]
Row[{plot1,plot2}]


In the second system of equations the first equation is the surface of the first equation of the original system reflected in the xy plane.
